# Python: concatinating the string output

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have class which holds a an integer and another list holds the data.

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, ID = str()):
        self.id = ID
        self.neighbors = AdjacencyList()
```

Adjacency list is another class. which holds a list.

I would to print the id and the list in the neighbors with a single print statement. How it's possible?

This is the code I use right now (employing string concatenation)

```
def printGraph(g = Graph()):
    msg = str('')
    for k, v in g.nodes.iteritems():
        root_node = g.nodes[k]
        msg = "(" + k + " , " + str(root_node.color) + ") : "

        for x in v.neighbors.innerlist:
            msg += str(x.id) + " , "
        print msg
```

You can see the whole string separators I used in the print method.

Comment: have you tried anything that didn't worked?

Comment: @sarat. Where is `Graph()` coming from?

Comment: @RohitJain consider it as a custom class where it has few members (in a dictionary and iterating over it as you can see in the code.

Comment: Did you even notice that **g.nodes[k]** and **v** are the same values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function to format your output: -

```
print "Id: {0}, Neighbour: {1}".format(self.id, self.neighbours)
```

This will work in `Python 2.6+`. For older version, you might need to use the one in the @Daniel's answer.

From `Python 2.7`, you can also omit that positional argument and just use `{}`: -

```
print "Id: {}, Neighbour: {}".format(self.id, self.neighbours)
```

Comment: I updated the question. You might be able to help me better. I want again format the neighbors attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can also use string formatting:

```
print('id: %s, neigbors: %s' % (self.id, str(self.neighbors)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
def printGraph(g = Graph()):
    for k, v in g.nodes.iteritems():
        msg = "({0} , {1}) : {2}".format(k, v.color, ", ".join(["{0}".format(x.id) for x in v.neighbors.innerlist]))
        print msg
```

As you see, the trick for building the whole string in just one step is to replace the last `for` loop with a list comprehension which is, in place, converted into a string and included in the initial string. This way you print the list items individually instead of printing the list object so you can:

- give the desired output format to items
- print items attributes

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it - and it's sort of unreadable, but in one line it should be something like

```
print '\n'.join(('({},{}):{}'.format(key, node.color,
                                     ','.join('{}'.format(x) for x in node.neighbors.innerlist)) 
                for key, node in g.nodes.iteritems())
```